# Курсовая работа с использованием xlsxwriter

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь реализовать курсовую работу, где необходимо рассчитать отдельные элементы радиоприемников.

Много формул, много переменных. 
Подскажите, в каком пути двигаться?
Рассчитываю параметры просто последовательным способом, используя глобальные переменные. Но, значений очень много для каждого из видов транзистора, и очень легко потеряться из-за большого количества формул, и похожих обозначений.

Теперь пытаюсь реализовать это с помощью xlsxwriter, для автоматического заполнения ячеек данными параметров.

```py
import xlsxwriter as xw 

wbKyrsovaya = xw.Workbook('/storage/emulated/0/Xlsx/Kyrsovaya.xlsx')
wsKyrsovaya = wbKyrsovaya.add_worksheet('Kyrsovaya')

f0i = input("f0: ")

tth = (
    ['Обозначение', 'Параметр', 'Данные'],
    ['f0', 'граничная частота в Гц', f0i],
)


row_number = 0
col_number = 0

for Обозн, Парам, Данн in tth:
    wsKyrsovaya.write(row_number, col_number, Обозн)
    wsKyrsovaya.write(row_number, col_number+1, Парам)
    wsKyrsovaya.write(row_number, col_number+2, Данн)
    row_number += 1

wbKyrsovaya.close()
```

Comment: формулы ведь в экселе можно расчитать

Comment: @Buzzard это говнокод)

Comment: @Интик, в чём заключается проблема, или вы просто поделиться хотите своим проектом?

Comment: @Александр вы ошиблись

Comment: @Интик, так в чём заключается проблема?

Comment: @Александр в том что ВОПРОС задавал не я, а Paren Rabotyaga

Comment: @Интик, прошу прощения, я не обратил внимания, мне почему-то показалось, что вы задали вопрос :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109030/discussion-between--and-).

Comment: @Paren Rabotyaga, в чём заключается вопрос?